# Simple JWT add extra field to payload data in token

Tags: django, djoser, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I use djoser and rest_framework_simplejwt. This my user model;

```
class userProfile(models.Model):

    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="profile")
    date_joined=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

My views.py to get token for users give in below;

```
class CustomTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):

serializer_class = CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer
token_obtain_pair = TokenObtainPairView.as_view()
```

This is the serializer.py;

```
class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
def validate(self, attrs):
    data = super(CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer, self).validate(attrs)
    data.update({'user': self.user.username})
    data.update({'id': self.user.id})
    data.update({'first_name': self.user.first_name})
    data.update({'last_name': self.user.last_name})
    data.update({'is_superuser': self.user.is_superuser})
    return data
```

I can get access and refresh token like this.

```
    {
    "refresh": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTU4ODQxMDY0OCwianRpIjoiNTY2MDhhOGVjYzRiNDZhMmFjYjc0Y2VmMzE2ZGE4YTkiLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjo3fQ.gXk9y3Vq0NlB8ZpU9SFcLWAMplr4_ECTeBg5WTMAuNY",
    "access": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTg4NDA5NzQ4LCJqdGkiOiIxM2VlYzQ1MjZkMTQ0ODI4YjgxNjVkZTA0MzlmYjBmMSIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjd9.sQ1G3rur1h3yqj79ZYvzHK1o6mgtHYuzJZlh5OCyg84",
    "user": "x",
    "id": 5,
    "first_name": "x",
    "last_name": "x",
    "is_superuser": false,

}
```

When encode token using jwt.io payload data is;

```
{
  "token_type": "access",
  "exp": 1588329561,
  "jti": "944f97343b42448fbaf5461295eb0548",
  "user_id": 5
}
```

I want to add users first_name, last_name in payload in access token and ı want to get;

```
    {
          "token_type": "access",
          "exp": 1588329561,
          "jti": "944f97343b42448fbaf5461295eb0548",
          "user_id": 5,
          "user": "x",
          "first_name": "x",
          "last_name": "x",
          "is_superuser": false,
 }
```

Comment: You can simply override your view to add whatever additional fields you need from your user model.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I change my CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer to:

```
class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)
        token['first_name'] = user.first_name
        token['last_name'] = user.last_name
        token['username'] = user.username
        token['is_superuser'] = user.is_superuser
        return token
```

Comment: how can you extract the customfields from the token?

Comment: @Lobbel I'm not sure I understand the problem but if it's like i understand you can use JWT decode.

Comment: I already fixed it thank you. I have another question, is it possible to send a image along with the tokens ? It seems like its only possible to send text back

Comment: @Lobbel you can ask as a new question. I think only possible to send text.

Comment: This only add fields to view response, not add fields to the token payload being encoded.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the data to the body of your response if you don't want to decode the JWT.

```
class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super().validate(attrs)
        data['first_name'] = self.user.first_name
        data['last_name'] = self.user.last_name
        data['username'] = self.user.username
        data['is_superuser'] = self.user.is_superuser
        return data
```

Comment: I tried but it is not working. @uyarc answer solved the issue.